# CSS - Bootstrap navbar element vertical middle

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When some element inside the navbar is larger, other element will not be center & align to each other. An example can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/3c236jft/3/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><img src="http://thevectorlab.net/metrolab/img/avatar-mini.png" class="img-circle"> Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

How can I make every element to be vertical center to navbar and not causing trouble to other element such as dropdown menu?

Comment: It is because of the image size..

Comment: @TryingToImprove Yeah I know. But how can I make other element center, if want to put image like that?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to adjust that for every item you add extra that is not standard.

Here I have updated your fiddle to work with dropdowns etc, and also taken the image into consideration:

http://jsfiddle.net/Preben/3c236jft/2/

[image]

Edited the code here: (I added the `nopadding`inside the `class="..."`

```
<li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nopadding" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><img src="http://thevectorlab.net/metrolab/img/avatar-mini.png" class="img-circle"> Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>../li>
```

The css I added:

```
a.dropdown-toggle.nopadding {padding-top:8px;padding-bottom:0px;}
```